# How to avoid : " The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to.."

Tags: java, hibernate, list, criteria, restrictions

I have this code :

```
List<Book> bookList = session.createCriteria(Book.class)
                .add(Restrictions.like("name", "%i%")).list();
```

But, i have a notice which say : 
"Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List"

How can i, fix my code for remove this warning?

Comment: I guess it's because `list()` returns a raw list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this above the line or in top of the method header:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Book> bookList = session.createCriteria(Book.class)
            .add(Restrictions.like("name", "%i%")).list();
```

or for the whole method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void doSomething(){
```

in case list() would be your own implementation you could define the result like this:

```
private List<Book> list(){
    return new ArrayList<Book>();
  }
```

then the `annotation` is not necessary and you have a `checked conversion` controlled by the compiler.

Comment: It might make the warning go away, but there is still an unchecked conversion there. Better to fix `list()` if possible.

Comment: Its Hibernate. OP cannot *fix* it. If you really want to avoid this, you should cast every item of the list into the desired class. In Java 8, you can do that by using streams very easily.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this adding an method to cast the List.

First add this method into your class:

```
public static <T> List<T> castList(Class<? extends T> clazz, Collection<?> c) {
    List<T> r = new ArrayList<T>(c.size());
    for(Object o: c)
      r.add(clazz.cast(o));
    return r;
}
```

Then try this:

```
List<Book> bookList = castList(Book.class,
    session.createCriteria(Book.class).add(Restrictions.like("name", "%i%")).list());
```

Comment: Or you can use streams: `return c.stream().map(clazz::cast).collect(Collectors.toList());`